# CakePHP SQL Log - How to check the SQL Logs from previous requests?

Tags: sql, cakephp, logging, cakephp-debug-kit

I'm trying to learn CakePHP using the Bookmark tutorial.

When I use the "baked" application forms to create or edit new Entities, they typically redirect to the index action following successful submission.  At this point, the Sql Log in the Debug Kit only shows the SQL used to generate the index listing, not the Sql that was used to do the update.

Is there an easy way to see the Sql that was used for creates/updates in the Debug Kit Sql Log either before or after submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug Kit stores a history of requests, which you can inspect at any point.

1. Head over to the **History** tab
2. Click on the last `POST`/`PUT` request
3. Head back to the **Sql Log** tab

You should now see the queries from the previous request.

See also **[Cookbook > DebugKit > Using the History Panel](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#using-the-history-panel)**

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!